# Excel formula to get zero if not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> In Excel I need a formula that adds cells A1 through C1 but does not show zeros unless Cell D2 is not blank. I have this formula

```
= IF(Sum(A1:C1)=0,"",Sum(A1:C1))
= IF(ISblank(D2),"",If(Sum(A1:C1)=0,"",Sum(A1:C11)))
```

Comment: Check for blanks with `isblank()`

Comment: i need those combined within the same cell

Comment: does not show zeros unless Cell D2 is not blank ?

Answer (score 3):

**Try this formula I think it helps**

```
=IF(B1="","",SUM(A1,C1))
```

OR
    //As per comment about isblank

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",SUM(A1,C1))
```

> Update As per comment (If same isblank check need for D)

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B1),ISBLANK(D1)),"",SUM(A1,C1))
```

Comment: Should D2 be involved here?

Comment: Involved means? You want to sum of A1 to D1?

Comment: I don't know. I think you are on the right path just don't yet know why OP is referring to "does not show zeros unless Cell D2 is not blank". Presumably, column D is involved somehow.

Comment: In the absence of the op bothering to clarify yup this gets my +1